# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'write' in json.dump

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7.14 .

When execute this,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        unicode_literals)
import os
import json

def main():
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data-creation.json')
    with open(path, 'r+') as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)
        json.dump(json_data, path)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

it says `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'write'` in line of `json.dump(json_data, path)` .

`nkf -g data-creation.json`

outputs `ASCII`, but what is wrong?
I think this is a matter of char code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dump` expects a file-like object which supports `write()` as second parameter, not a path.